# VBA Multiple Word Tables to Excel - No Tables in Document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I exported all of the tables from a large Word document a few months ago, then my computer went and lost the VBA I had used...Note ++ decided to disappear and take all my files with it.

So, I have looked up several different options that are out there to pull all the tables from a Word file to Excel.

Every one I try says there are no tables in the Word file.  I have tried multiple files, all the same thing.

The only other change in my environment is I upgraded to Windows 10.

I have racked my brain and cannot figure out why it is not seeing the tables?

I can copy the tables to a different word file:

```
Sub CopyTables()
Dim Source As Document
Dim Target As Document
Dim tbl As Table
Dim tr As Range

Set Source = ActiveDocument
Set Target = Documents.Add

For Each tbl In Source.Tables
    Set tr = Target.Range
    tr.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    tr.FormattedText = tbl.Range.FormattedText
    tr.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    tr.Text = vbCrLf
Next
End Sub
```

And I can find the Table Number in the word file:

```
Sub FindTableNumber()
Dim J As Integer
Dim iTableNum As Integer
Dim oTbl As Table

Selection.Bookmarks.Add ("TempBM")
For J = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
    Set oTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(J)
    oTbl.Select
    If Selection.Bookmarks.Exists("TempBM") Then
        iTableNum = J
        Exit For
    End If
Next J
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TempBM").Select
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TempBM").Delete
MsgBox "The current table is table " & iTableNum
End Sub
```

This is an example of the VBA I have tried, and received the No Tables in Document:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & "     tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If

    resultRow = 4

    For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
        With .tables(tableStart)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell    (iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                Next iCol
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next iRow
        End With
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next tableStart
End With

End Sub
```